# Problem with iterables (Sum and for loops)

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a code to find out the if a number is divisible by 3. The steps go like this, enter number, add all digits, if digits greater than 10 add digits together until below 10, see if the digit remaining is 3, 6 or 9 and then print out if it is divisible by 3 or not.
Here is my code so far:

```
user_input = int(input('Enter number: '))
sum = 0
for num in user_input:
    sum += int(num)

    if sum > 10:
        while sum > 10:
            sum = 0
            for num in user_input:
                sum += int(num)

            if sum == 3 or 6 or 9:
                print('Your number is divisble by 3')

            else:
                print('Your number is not divisible by 3')

    else:

        if sum == 3 or 6 or 9:
            print('Your number is divisble by 3')

        else:
            print('Your number is not divisible by 3')
```

Anyone know how to fix the bug?

Comment: thanks a lot for that missed that bit

Comment: `if sum > 10:` should be outside your for loop that counts the sum

Comment: Why do you need to sum a number to check divisible by 3? `int(user_input) % 3 == 0` is the most common way to do that

Comment: I am trying to find a different way to find a number that's divisible by 3 thanks

Comment: Okay... If the very last digit is 3,6,9... `user_input[-1] in {'3' ,'6' ,'9' }` and some rule about units of 10 that I forgot

Comment: If you want to sum numbers, I can advise you to focus on making a function to do exactly that. Then, never indent code unless it uses variables from the if statement or loop

Comment: It's a different way I am learning to find the divisibility rule for 3

Comment: The problem is that it says |  for num in user_input:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: This is from line 3

Answer (score 1):

Replace every:

```py
if sum == 3 or 6 or 9:
```

With

```py
if (sum in ( 3, 6, 9)):
```

Also - don't override`sum` - it's default function in python, you can name your variable like `_sum` for instance.

**Edit**:

IIUC, this is what you're trying to do (you insert multiple numbers delimited by white space initially):

```py
user_input = input('Enter numbers: ').split(" ")

for num1 in user_input:
    sum1 = int(num1)
    if sum1 > 10:
        while sum1 > 10:
            sum_=sum1
            sum1=0
            for num in str(sum_):
                sum1 += int(num)
        if sum1 in (3, 6, 9):
            print(num1, ': Your number is divisble by 3')
        else:
            print(num1, ': Your number is not divisible by 3')
```

To just get and process single number:

```py
user_input = input('Enter number: ')

sum1 = num1 = int(user_input)

if sum1 > 10:
    while sum1 > 10:
        sum_=sum1
        sum1=0
        for num in str(sum_):
            sum1 += int(num)
    if sum1 in (3, 6, 9):
        print(num1, ': Your number is divisble by 3')
    else:
        print(num1, ': Your number is not divisible by 3')
```

Comment: sorry but that's not the problem it happens on line 3

Comment: @Fort it's one of the problems. Indentation is the other

Comment: Ah, right for line 3 just don't convert user input to ```int``` in line 2 it will iteratate over all characters - digits - then.

Comment: can you help me with that please thanks

Comment: Why you're putting surrounding parenthesis, why not just `if sum in (3, 6, 9):`?

Comment: For readability, but you're right it's redundant